# How to reload a particular tab in bottom navigation bar flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a bottom navigation bar with 5 tabs, In each tab I have a button that navigates to another separate screen using `Navigation.pushNamed()`(page 2); and from (page 2) I pop the screen, now the tab from where I navigated from need to be reloaded. because i store some data (page 2) and stored in sqflite i need to display the data in one of the tabs. Is it possible to reload a particular tab of a bottom navigation bar?
I tried using `Navigator.pop(context,true)` that also didnt work. Can some one help me with this, thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use the provider for it

Comment: can you give me a bits of code? I am new to flutter @jitsm555

Answer (score 0):

Flutter by default does not save state (and disposes the widgets). If you want to save the state of a tab, you can use a PageStorageBucket. It is really well described in this tutorial:

https://medium.com/@lucassaltoncardinali/keeping-state-with-the-bottom-navigation-bar-in-flutter-69e4168878e1

Comment: I need to reload like onresume in android lifecycle, is it possible to do that? @Candace

Comment: Sorry Im not familiar with that.

You can store anything you want in the bucket using a key, then in `initState()`, you can check the bucket to see if theres anything stored and use that data to rebuild.

For example I made a custom class `HomeData` that stores all the information needed, and then I save that object to my bucket (using a PageStorageKey). Then when I rebuild that page, I have all the info I need regarding what the user clicked, etc. I even have the route stored (bc I push different pages within each tab).

Answer (score -1):

this is done by the provider. I'm new to flutter as well but [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O71rYKcxUgA&list=PLNnAcB93JKV-IarNvMKJv85nmr5nyZis8) explained it very well!

Comment: Can you tell me more precisely? in which video he did that?

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. That YouTube video is a general introduction to `provider`.